# Keeping data between intents from WebHook in Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to build a movie bot, and I need to save the ID from a movie which I got via my webhook, and keep it in a place where can be access by the follow up intents in that context.

Right now I'm using the payload in fulfillment to pass data to the first intent, but in the follow up intents that data is lost.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably include the data you want remembered across intents in a [context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts). You should set the lifespan to be long enough for all the intents that will need the info.